# How to fix _token error on 'Illuminate \ Database \ Eloquent \ MassAssignmentException'

Tags: php, laravel

I have facing this error when try to add new categories to store the data, but it seen show me _token error?

CategoriesController.php

```
public function store(Request $request)
{
    Category::create($request->all());
    return back();
}
```

index.blade.php

```
<a class="btn btn-primary pull-right navbar-right" data-toggle="modal" href="#category">Add Category</a>
<div class="modal fade" id="category">
    <div class="modal-dialog">
        <div class="modal-content">
            <div class="modal-header">
                <button type="button" class="close" data-dismiss="modal" aria-hidden="true">&times;</button>
                <h4 class="modal-title">Add New</h4>
            </div>
            {!! Form::open(['route' => 'category.store', 'method' => 'post']) !!}
            <div class="modal-body">
                <div class="form-group">
                    {{ Form::label('name', 'Title') }}
                    {{ Form::text('name', null, array('class' => 'form-control')) }}

                </div>


            </div>
            <div class="modal-footer">
                <button type="button" class="btn btn-default" data-dismiss="modal">Close</button>
                <button type="submit" class="btn btn-primary">Save changes</button>
            </div>
            {!! Form::close() !!}
        </div><!-- /.modal-content -->
    </div><!-- /.modal-dialog -->
</div><!-- /.modal -->
```

[image]

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Add

```
protected $fillable = ['name'];
```

under your `Category` class.

And use

```
Category::create($request->only(['name']));
```

instead of `$request->all()` which tries to write to `categories._token` column inside your Category model combined with `create()`.

Comment: oh...i forgot put the fillable in the category model. Thanks!

Comment: I'm glad I was able to help.

Answer (score 0):

You should try this:

```
<a class="btn btn-primary pull-right navbar-right" data-toggle="modal" href="#category">Add Category</a>
<div class="modal fade" id="category">
    <div class="modal-dialog">
        <div class="modal-content">
            <div class="modal-header">
                <button type="button" class="close" data-dismiss="modal" aria-hidden="true">&times;</button>
                <h4 class="modal-title">Add New</h4>
            </div>
            {!! Form::open(['route' => 'category.store', 'method' => 'post']) !!}

            {!! csrf_field() !!}

            <div class="modal-body">
                <div class="form-group">
                    {{ Form::label('name', 'Title') }}
                    {{ Form::text('name', null, array('class' => 'form-control')) }}

                </div>


            </div>
            <div class="modal-footer">
                <button type="button" class="btn btn-default" data-dismiss="modal">Close</button>
                <button type="submit" class="btn btn-primary">Save changes</button>
            </div>
            {!! Form::close() !!}
        </div><!-- /.modal-content -->
    </div><!-- /.modal-dialog -->
</div><!-- /.modal -->
```

Answer (score 0):

you can also add

```
protected $guarded = [];
```

to your model and then you can use mass assignment.